# PHPUnit: assert E_USER_WARNING is generated as expected without ending a test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to test code to show that it produces an `E_USER_WARNING` in certain circumstances.

I found [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/testing-error-conditions-with-phpunit/) which addresses the problem, so as I see it I have these options:

1. Copying that code into every TestSuite which needs to test for warnings
2. Making a subclass of `PHPUnit's` TestCase that has that code, and have my tests inherit from that
3. Use composition, i.e. make a helper class that achieves the same.

I don't like 1, for obvious reasons - I can't imagine the author had that option in mind.

I don't like 2, because there are some tests that I might use a third party TestCase that already extends `PHPUnit's` TestCase, so it would get complicated or messy if I wanted to add that functionality for that subclass as well by subclassing that subclass.

Option 3 sounds the best. But...

**This all seems to be reinventing the wheel. Aren't there any off-the-shelf solutions for PHPUnit to assert a warning has been generated as expected? If not, is there a good pattern for this that anyone could share?**

For better or worse, I very strongly want to stick with `PHPUnit` for reasons such as:

- I want to keep my tests consistent, and not have to re-write all my current tests
- It is the most supported `PHP` test framework for `IDEs` etc
- I don't want to have to learn another framework

Answer (score 3):

You can configure PHPUnit to convert notices, warnings and errors to exception by modifying your `phpunit.xml` file, see https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html .

For instance, if you set `convertWarningsToExceptions` to `true`, you can catch the warning by setting the expected exception to `\PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`, like this:

```
/**
 * @expectedException \PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning
 */
public function testFoo()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but say I use a data provider and the test method will in some cases require an error, and in others require no error, how would this be achieved?

Comment: I think the solution here would be to create separate tests with separate data providers - one for testing that errors occur, the other to test that no errors occur.

Comment: I think a better solution would be to use the `self::expectException(\Exception::class)` method in a condition based on your dataProvider.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not solve your problem, we went with option 2: write a BaseTestCase that adds functionality to the PHPUnit's `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.

It has been published under the MIT license as [Netsilik/BaseTestCase](https://github.com/Netsilik/BaseTestCase) and can be installed using composer:

`composer require netsilik/base-test-case`

Testing for `E_WARNING`, `E_NOTICE`, `E_USER_WARNING`, etc. is now rather simple

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

class MyTestCase extends \Netsilik\Testing\BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $this->_convertNoticesToExceptions  = false;
        $this->_convertWarningsToExceptions = false;
        $this->_convertErrorsToExceptions   = true;
    }

    public function test_whenWarningTriggered_weCanTestForIt()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->bar();

        self::assertErrorTriggered(E_WARNING, 'The warning string');
    }
}
```

We also tried to achieve the same using Traits, but the resulting solution was far from elegant.